# React.js Run Client Side JS After Render Finishes

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a React app, but I need to run some client side js once the component has finished loading. What is the best way to run js that interacts with the DOM like `$('div').mixItUp()` once the render function has finished and loaded. Very new to React so sorry if this is stupidly easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your code inside the `componentDidMount` method on your component. See the documentation on [lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount). With ES6 syntax, this will look like

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    ...
    componentDidMount() {
        $('div').mixItUp();
    }
    ...
}
```